# PostgreSQL. Create nested json objects

Tags: json, postgresql

Inside of my postgres function, I have a set of json:

```
{"layer_name":"rooms","properties":{"fillOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"#606576","strokeWidth":"3"}}
{"layer_name":"map","properties":{"fillColor":"#3D404F"}}
```

I need to modify it to a structure:

```
{
  "rooms": {"fillOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"#606576","strokeWidth":"3"}},
  "map: {"fillColor":"#3D404F"}
}
```

I've tried to iterate through the set and fill two arrays (one for keys, other vor falues) so I could use `json_object(keys text[], values text[])` to create needed json:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION appearance.get_styles(out response text)
  RETURNS text
AS
$BODY$
  declare
    vResult json;
    i json;
    keys TEXT[];
    vals TEXT[];
    layers json;
begin
  with a as (SELECT layer_name, properties FROM appearance.styles)
  select json_agg(a)
    into vResult
    from a;

  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(vResult)  
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'props %', i;
    keys = array_append(keys, i->>'layer_name');
    vals = array_append(vals, i->>'properties');

  END LOOP;
    layers = json_object(keys, vals);
    RAISE NOTICE 'props %', layers;

 response := concat ('"layersStyles"', ':', coalesce(layers::text,'[]'));
 response := '{' || response || '}';

end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

But the problem is that I have to cast `json` into `text`, and in the end I get escaped string as a value:

```
"map" : "{\"fillColor\":\"#3D404F\"}", "rooms" : "{\"fillOpacity\":1,\"strokeColor\":\"#606576\",\"strokeWidth\":\"3\"}"}
```

And that is not what I need. I can not figure out how to make  nested `json` objects. Don't see any function for it [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html). Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the help of `json_object_agg` function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION appearance.get_styles(out response text)
  RETURNS text
AS
$BODY$
  declare
    vResult json;    
begin  
  SELECT json_object_agg("layer_name", "properties") from appearance.styles
    into vResult;  
  response := concat ('"layersStyles"', ':', coalesce(vResult::text,'[]'));
  response := '{' || response || '}';

end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;
```